# How to share const between some Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, httprequest, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to do an http request which redirects to 3rd party end point and gets back to another Firebase function url. How can I share user uid between these two functions since the second function is not triggered from my side but is sending is sending to my app?

user uid can change as different users try to connect to the 3rd party end point.

Here's the function which receives the request and redirects to 3rd party end point:

```
exports.triggeredFromApp = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    res.redirect(AUTHORIZE_URI + '?' + qs.stringify({
      response_type: 'code',
      client_id: functions.config().tokens.client_id
    }));
});
```

later this function is triggered coming back from 3rd party website:

```
exports.backToApp = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

 ....************here I need to know clien'ts uid*********
           res.status(200).send({'key': key});      
 ...
}
```

Comment: If it's an OAuth 2.0 flow, you should be able to pass a `state` query parameter to the 3rd party which will then be passed back to you in turn.

Comment: It's not really , I'm trying to communicate with Stripe and get customers tokens. So it's similar to OAuth flow but i am not aware if their end point supports something like a state

Comment: better to say it is an OAuth 2 flow.